# does docker support all type on data inside container

Tags: android, apache, cordova, docker, jenkins

I am building cordova project where I build and add browser and android platforms.

In dockerfile I have

```
ADD . /var/www/html/
```

Where . is my current Jenkins  work space.  When I browse using Apache which in on container I can't see my Android and browser builds.

```
jenkins@ip-172-31-22-20:~/workspace/qa_vast2net_pp_docker$ ls PatientPortal/platforms/
android/        browser/        platforms.json
```

[image]

Note : I am running on Ubuntu which is on aws instance

$ docker ps -a

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                                     COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS                  NAMES
1d8a8eb3fb63        qa_vast2net_pp_docker                                                     "ls -l /"                8 minutes ago       Exited (0) 8 minutes ago                          boring_wilson
52b5b9ef1bc8        XXXX.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/qa_global_pp_docker:latest   "/bin/sh -c 'apachec…"   8 minutes ago       Up 8 minutes               0.0.0.0:8086->80/tcp   qa_vast2net_pp_docker
1e6546425dc0        XXXX.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/qa_global_pp_docker:latest   "/bin/sh -c 'apachec…"   36 minutes ago      Up 36 minutes              0.0.0.0:8085->80/tcp   qa_global_pp_docker
```

My question is : does docker support all type on data inside container ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use 2 ADD commands one for android folder and other for browser

```
ADD android/ /var/www/html/          
ADD browser/ /var/www/html/
```

If you want same directory structure in container.

Use COPY instead which is recommended as using ADD is not really necessary here.
Chek for difference in ADD and COPY here.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add